# Assigning a variable to an array

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to assign an array and integer, this is the code i have. Say eg1 is 5, when i print arr[1][1], i want it to display 5

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d", &eg1, &eg2, &eg3, &eg4);    
Arr[1][1] = eg1;
printf(" %c", Arr[1][1])
```

Comment: You'll need to improve your question if you want some help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some ideas on how to improve it.

Comment: @SupportUkraine That fixed it, i knew it was some stupid syntax error, ThankYou Live Saver

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want an array of pointers to the variables `eg1` to `eg4` to be able to display any changes to those variables via the array. You need a 1D array of `int*` for this. Not a 2D array.

Example:

```
int eg1, eg2, eg3, eg4;
int *Arr[] = {&eg1, &eg2, &eg3, &eg4}; // fill Arr with pointers to the variables

if (fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d", &eg1, &eg2, &eg3, &eg4) == 4) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("eg%d = %d\n", i+1, *Arr[i]); // derefrence pointer to get the value
    }
}
```

Note that you `fscanf` for `int`:s with `%d` but you `printf` a `char` with `%c`. I assume you meant `%d` in your `printf` too.